# I use react paginate to make pagination and active and breaklabel doesn't work when I setloading in each page

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, react-paginate

[this getPage function l call api and sent currentPage as parameter[ and this is handlPageCLick when I click on page call this function and l call also getPage and update state setdrivers when l remove setloading active and breaklabel is work and when l put setloading active and break label doesn't work[and this is ReactPaginate component and onpagechange call handlePageCLick and all classname I took it from bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylx3z.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBZvM.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjrSy.jpg)

I want to handle active and breaklabel when I click on any page active work and breaklabel also

Comment: Please share with us your actual code(bare in mind not sharing private keys or any sensitive data) so it would be easier to assist.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.